# How do a sftp uri look alike?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I am new to SFTP,

For the ftp, the link will appear as

```
ftp://servername/folder/
```

We can see the list of files in that link.

To look on a specific file, the link will be mentioned as

```
ftp://servername/folder/test.txt
```

How do a SFTP uri look alike ?

Comment: Irrespective of downvotes, i received one answer. I thank for that.

Comment: It's defined here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04#section-4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no official standard.  But sftp://server/path is what is suggested.  There is an [IETF draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-01) that proposed that.

Almost no browser natively supports sftp though.  You need a sftp client installed for sftp support.  So using that type of link is not likely to be very useful.

One client you might use for this is WinSCP.  There is [documentation about the protocol handlers](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url) it can support.